# Print True for specific ID# holding different values (Python)

Tags: python, apply, func

Question
Using Python 2.7, how can I get the following result after my code below:

1) If an ID 'x' (1st column) holds True and False values--> print out "ID 'x' is True" else it's False

For example: ID 455 should be False and ID 320 should be True

```
My Code:

for i in range(1,6):
    if rawdata.iat[i,5]=='2'and rawdata.iat[i,8]>0 or rawdata.iat[i,5]=='1'and rawdata.iat[i,8]==0:
        print ([rawdata.iat[i,0], True])
    else:
        print ([rawdata.iat[i,0], False])
  ['455', False]
  ['455', False]
  ['320', False]
  ['320', False]
  ['320', True]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you simplify your code, so it's narrowed down to the minimum? And possibly clean up your question so it's easier to understand what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the ID value to True: `320 = True`... Then you could use a if statement like `if ID == True: do something;`

You can also search "identifying booleans in python", like to see if the variable is a bool, but I don't think it will work out with numbers...

PS.: declare the bools before the `for` loop you're using... Variables are executed like any loop: top to bottom